# не применяется стиль к первому элементу

Tags: html, css

Согласно описаниям, найденным мной в сети, псевдокласс :first-child применяет стилевое оформление к первому дочернему элементу своего родителя. Простой код:

```css
#top{
  background-color:aliceblue;
}
#top a{
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:1px solid gray;
  line-height:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  padding:15px;
}
#top>a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
#top:first-child{
  border-left:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='top' align=center>
  <a id='back' href='ya.ru'>назад</a>
  <a id='ahead'>вперед</a>
</div>
```

Когда я пытаюсь его применить к первому дочернему элементу элемента #top (первый ), то не получаю ожидаемого. Вместо этого вижу эту границу у самого #top.

В чем я ошибся в своем понимании?

Comment: для дочернего элемента должно быть `#top>a:first-child`. В этом примере стиль применяться для первого элемента с id `#top`

Comment: что за древний атрибут align=center? не надо его использовать

Comment: @Air, я знаю, что он древний. Но это набросок. Кроме того, у меня какой-то стереотип, что html-атрибут должен применяться и отрисовываться быстрее, чем его css аналог, т.к. проверяется в первую очередь

Comment: Ну мы же не в детском саду... Ей богу.... Да хоть в миллиард раз быстрее отрисуется... На кой его скорость, если может всю верстку сломать.... Так что советую, еще куча старых тегов и атрибутов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#top` есть контейнер, а дочерние между внутри подобными - в этом случае тег `а`

```css
#top{
  background-color:aliceblue;
}
#top a{
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:1px solid gray;
  line-height:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  padding:15px;
}
#top>a:hover{
  background-color:gray;
}
#top a:first-child{
  border-left:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='top' align=center>
  <a id='back' href='ya.ru'>назад</a>
  <a id='ahead'>вперед</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает

Comment: Пожалуйста), хорошо!